# R, variable name missing in returned object, ddply, function(x)

Tags: r, function, plyr

When this code is run why does the variable name result_var_all not show up in v?  Its just the variable name itself I'm asking about. Otherwise the code works fine.

```
 v<-ddply(y1,.(metric_name), result_var_all<-function(x) {
      y1a<-x[match(unique(x[,2]),x[,2]),] 
      y1b<-(y1a$event)
      y1c<-subset(x,x[,1] %in% (y1b))
      var(y1c$result_value)
      })
```

I also tried this variation, which again runs to completion, but gives the same result for every value of field = metric_name in the sample data (NA for this small data set and a numeric value in the larger data set).  Why is that?

```
z1<-split(y1,y1[,3])   
lapply(z1, function(x) {
    y1a<-x[match(unique(x[,2]),x[,2]),]      
    y1b<-(y1a$event)
    y1c<-subset(x,x[,1] %in% (y1b))
    x["result_var_all"]<-var(y1c$result_value)
    out<-x
    return(out)})


m<-rep(c("a1","a2","a3","b1","b2","b3","c1","c2","c3"),2)
n<-rep(c(rep(letters[1],3),rep(letters[2],3),rep(letters[3],3)),2)
p<-rep(c("width","depth","count"),6)
r<-c(sample((100:200),9),sample((20:50),9))
y1<-data.frame(m,n,p,r)
colnames(y1)<-c("event","site","metric_name","result_value")
```

This is a module in a longer script in which the filters subset to the target record set, for about 300 metrics.  Not all sites have the same metrics and some sites have multiple events.

Comment: There is no column named `data_collection_event` in 'y1a'

Comment: The sample data should now match.

Comment: You are assigning the "result_var_all" to the `var(y1c$result_value)` which is a single value.  So you get a single value as output which gets populated to the entire row due to recycling.  If there are NA values, you need to use `var(..., na.rm=TRUE)`